# How to access the next item of a list, inside the (for item in list) loop ? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

**Imagine an imaginary list**

```
for item in list: 
    print(item)      
    print(_________) # Fill the blanks to print next item in list
```

I would seek a code that replaces **only** the blank of the above code to print next item on list.

Comment: Check out the `itertools` recipe for [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only work if there are no duplicate entries in the list. I changed the name of the list to `data` because it's a bad idea to overwrite the name of the builtin `list` (and even if it's an example I can't force myself to do that).

```
data = ['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C']
for item in data: 
    print(item)      
    print(data[data.index(item) + 1])
```

At the moment this code crashes for the last element because it tries to access the element after the last. You could fix that by replacing the line with `print('' if data.index(item) + 1 == len(data) else data[data.index(item) + 1])`.

I hope that the question is about homework or something like that, because noone would/should write code like this in real production.

Comment: lol nope, it's just a question that popped up in my mind, I expected something like this, thanks alot for your effort (and list = data). I guess we can duplicate the list and loop on it, removing the item after each iteration to avoid the problem of duplication.

Comment: I'm so glad you told me that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use zip:

```
for item,nextItem in zip(list,list[1:]+[None]): 
    print(item)      
    print(nextItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
for i,item in enumerate(list):
    if i < len(list)-1:
        print(list[i])
        print(list[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend enumerating and then using the index to access the next one. You'll need to guard against out of range.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    print(val)
    print(list[idx+1])
```